# getting value out of onDataChange?

Tags: android, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[Database looks like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ijHYc.png)

I'm trying to get mail by username, so far I tried:

The `storageContainer` way by defining string variable on `MainActivity` class and using storageContainer Function in onDataChange function.

```
public void storageContainer(String mail){
    this.userMail = mail;
}
```

This is the `getMailByUsername` function:

```
public void getMailByUsername(String username){
    String user_mail;
    mDatabase.child("Users").child(username).child("email").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        String userMail;
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            userMail = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();
            storageContainer(userMail);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Comment: Im trying to get dataSnapshot.getValue().toString() out of onDataChange function :/ but i guess i can't ... im trying to get user mail from that database and  use it in logIn(String email,String password) function

Answer (score 4):

To solve this, move the declaration of `String user_mail` inside the `onDataChange()` method, otherwise it will be null. This is happening due the asynchronous behaviour of `onDataChange()` method, which is called before even your `storageContainer()` is called.

Moving the declaration inside the method, solves your problem. Use also a log statement inside the method like this:

```
Log("TAG", userMail);
```

If you want to use the value of that String outside that method, please take a look at my answer from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47847694/how-to-return-datasnapshot-value-as-a-result-of-a-method/47853774).